# MS Project 2003 with SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, ms-project

We are building a sharepoint 2013 site and in the process need to integrate some project plans(a set of tasks) into a sharepoint task list and then build a workflow. My problem has beef this possible: save project 2003 data in excel file and export it to list? Any suggestions on accomplishing this would be helpful.. Thank you..